# Canções Escravistas

Tags: palavra-para-ideia, sinônimos, definição

Estou trabalhando com a criação de legendas nas quais, vez ou outra, constam expressões compostas por uma terminologia musical acompanhada de alguma referência aplicável.

Neste momento procuro pela definição ou por um sinônimo referente às canções escravistas, que, historicamente falando, eram constantemente repetidas pelos escravos de/em um grupo, fosse nas senzalas ou em seus quilombos, se aplicáveis.

O mais próximo que cheguei foi a palavra [*Coro* (Dicio)](http://www.dicio.com.br/coro/), que cabe no contexto que preciso mas não tanto quanto eu gostaria.

Apesar desta ser uma Comunidade para o Português, caso ajude na contextualização do sinônimo, a expressão original, em inglês, é ***Freesong***.

Comment: Bruno, acrescentei o tag «palavra-para-ideia», que me parece ser o mais apropriado ao que tu pretendes: uma palavra ou expressão que signifique  'canções cantadas pelos escravos'. Procurei informar-me melhor sobre a *freesong*, mas não encontrei nada na net, nem vem nos dicionários de inglês; tens alguma referência?

Comment: Infelizmente não, nem mesmo uma cena, já que o termo é apenas falado, sem foco em rostos nem nada do tipo. A palavra em si não existe, é uma combinação de **Free** com **Song**. Dado o contexto escravista da cena fica claro que é um tipo de coro, cântico, rima (enfim, já que não sei XD) cantado ou mesmo repetido pelos escravos quando sós. Eu sei que tem uma palavra específica pra isso, só que não lembro bem das aulas de História u.u'

Comment: Não, a expressão em inglês não é freesong. Se chaman: slave songs. Mas como sempre em inglés, o pessoal inventa muita coisa.

Comment: Cantilena? Refrão? Estribilho? Rondó? Foram algumas que me lembrei e respectivas palavras relacionadas no Priberam http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/refr%C3%A3o http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/rond%c3%b3

Answer (score 4):

Creio que por "contextualização" você se refira não a uma tradução, propriamente dita, mas a alguma expressão que o leitor conheça e que possa entender por analogia/aproximação. No Brasil, no contexto de capoeira (também conhecido como "jogo de Angola"), existe o termo *ladainha*. Segundo a [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capoeira_de_Angola#Ladainha):

> O *jogo de Angola* é acompanhado por uma música mais lenta. Geralmente a música é antecedida por uma ladainha, que é uma espécie de lamento, que quase sempre fala da escravidão e da vida do escravizado.

Originalmente, ladainha (do latim *litania*) refere-se a um tipo de oração em forma de diálogo entre um sacerdote e a congregação.

Comment: Pena é a possível conotação pejorativa da palavra

Comment: Qual é o contexto da fala dos personagens?

Comment: Não tem contexto propriamente dito. O personagem está apenas lendo em voz alta uma carta, sozinho